# How to destined messages from an local queue manger to another queue manager of an local queue

Tags: ibm-mq

Hi I am preparing for an exam.
Can anyone able to help me find the correct answer.

An application connects to local queue manager QM1 and puts messages on remote queue QR1.

- QR1 has been defined with target queue QL2, target queue manager QM2,
  and XMITQ QM2.
- QL2 is defined as a local queue in QM2. For security purposes,
  another queue manager, QM3, has been created behind a firewall and
  all messages destined for QL2 on QM2 need to be routed to QL3 on QM3.

---

Assuming QM2 and QM3 are interconnected, what changes does the system administrator need to make to achieve this without application failure?

A. Create an alias queue on QM2 pointing to QL3 on QM3.

B. Create a remote queue on QM2 pointing to QL3 on QM3.

C. Alter the QR1 RQMNAME parameter to point to QM3 and RNAME parameter to QL3 with XMITQ QM2.

D. Alter the QR1 RQMNAME parameter to point to QM3 and RNAME parameter to QL3 with XMITQ QM3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the details provided in the question and the four answers provided C is the most correct.

There could still be impact to the application if QR1 is open for OUTPUT by the application at the time of the alter.  The application would either need to be stopped while the the QREMOTE is altered or the FORCE option would need to be used in which case the application would receive a MQRC 2041 (MQRC_OBJECT_CHANGED) the next time it attempted to PUT a message to the queue.  The FORCE option would require the application to handle that exception and reopen the queue, many application do not handle this exception so may need to be restarted anyway.

This answer also make assumptions that the RCVR channel from QM1 to QM2 is either not locked down with a low privileged MCAUSER or if it is locked down that it would have permission to put the the XMITQ QM3.

Answer B could be a potential solution as well if the original local queue QL2 on QM2 is deleted first and a new remote queue called QL2 is defined on QM2 which would point to QL3 on QM3.